# rename mulitple datasets after applying a function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to apply a function to different dataframes. After doing that I want to get the resulting dataframe and save them keeping their original names and adding something else to differentiate the new dataframes.

This is what I've tried, which is obviously not working.

```
#Creating dummi data
N <- 8 
df1 <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(N), x2 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), x3 = 1*(runif(n = N) < .75))
df2 <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(N), y2 = sample(100:200, size = N, replace = TRUE), y3 = runif(N))
df3 <- data.frame(z1 =rnorm(N), z2 = sample(8:80, size = N,replace = TRUE), Z3 = runif(N))

# Making a list of the three data frames
mydata <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3= df3)     

#Applying a function to mydata list
mydata2 <-  lapply(mydata, function(x) mean(unlist(x))) 

# Renaming each dataset
n <- 1:length(mydata2)
noms <- names(mydata2)
for (i in 1:n){
mynewlist <- lapply(mydata2, function(x) {names(x) <-("_mean", sep ="");
return(x))}
```

Please any help will be deeply apreciated.

Comment: Do you need `colMeans` ? instead of `mean` or is it ` `lapply(mydata, function(x) mean(unlist(x)))`

Comment: yeas, you were right it was `mydata2 <-  lapply(mydata, function(x) mean(unlist(x))) ` I've just edited the question

Comment: In that case, there is only single element for each dataset.  What is the expected output?

Comment: Perhaps `list2env(setNames(mydata2, paste0(names(mydata2), "_mean")), envir=.GlobalEnv)` and then check `df1_mean`

Comment: For this case i have a single element but I am also applying other functions where I get dataframes. The output that i expect is a new dataframe which i want to save keeping its old name and adding something else to differentiate it. Something like `df1_newname`

Comment: The `list2env` will give the output you expected (`df1_mean`, `df2_mean`) or whatever you are using in the `paste` function.

Comment: Thanks that works nicely! I did not know `list2env`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `list2env` if we need to create multiple objects in the global environment (though not recommended as most of the operations can be done within the `list` itself).

We change the `names` of the `list` by `paste`ing a suffix substring and then use `list2env`

```
list2env(setNames(mydata2, paste0(names(mydata2), 
                        "_newname")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
```